# Solidity: Can't access mapping when using array as ValueType

Tags: solidity

This contract allows users to checkin and stores last time it occurred:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract DSquare {

    mapping (address => uint) public checkins;

    function checkin() public {
        require(now - checkins[msg.sender] > 1 minutes);

        checkins[msg.sender] = now;
    }
}
```

In a second version intending to store all user's checkins, I've changed the ValueType from uint to uint[] resulting in this contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract DSquare {

    mapping (address => uint[]) public checkins;

    function checkin() public {
        uint[] storage userCheckins = checkins[msg.sender];
        if (userCheckins.length > 0) {
          require(now - userCheckins[userCheckins.length - 1] > 1 minutes);
        }

        userCheckins.push(now);
    }
}
```

After that I can't call the get function anymore. Using web3, it shows: "Uncaught Error: Invalid number of parameters for "checkins". Got 1 expected 2"

[image]

In the JSON file generated by Truffle I can see that it really has a second parameter:

```
"abi": [
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "address"
        },
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "name": "checkins",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ]
```

(The full JSON is here: https://gist.github.com/saulobrito/ebdd40dd610da23ece1c97c4c912b492)

Same thing on Remix. That's how it shows the first contract:

[image]

And here the second version:

[image]

Is this a bug? Shouldn't the get function depend only of the key? Any thoughts how working around it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mapping` is pointing to dynamic arrays (with an s). Each one of those also has an index. This is why it's asking for an addess *and* a uint.

You could build it manually and it would look something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract DSquare {

    mapping (address => uint[]) public checkins;

    function checkin() public {
        uint[] storage userCheckins = checkins[msg.sender];
        if (userCheckins.length > 0) {
          require(now - userCheckins[userCheckins.length - 1] > 1 minutes);
        }

        userCheckins.push(now);
    }

    function returnCheckinValue(address mapKey, uint arrayRow) public view returns(uint value) {
        return checkins[mapKey][arrayRow];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Humm, got it. Just a follow-up question: to get all checkins, I'd have to call a function like `returnCheckinValue` N (length) times, is that right? Thanks!

Comment: You could return the `uint[]` but it wasn't always that way and there are limitations. Since walking off the end as you crawl it is a bad way to discover the length of an array, I'd probably go with the `public mapping` plus a `function getMappedArrayLength(address mapKey) public view returns(uint count)  { return checkins[mspKey].length; }`

Comment: Just for reference, from solidity FAQ: "The automatic accessor function for a public state variable of array type only returns individual elements. If you want to return the complete array, you have to manually write a function to do that."